# Qt DownloadManager On Separate Thread Blocks Main GUI

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a program patch system that doesn't block the main gui of my qt application. (This is just to play around with Qt). For testing sake, the PatchManager is set to run an infinite loop to make sure it doesn't block.

I'm not understanding why my program is still blocking, even though my PatchManager/DownloadManager was sectioned off into a new thread (different from the GUI thread).

Can anybody help me here? Here's my code...

**downloadmanager.h**

```
#ifndef DOWNLOADMANAGER_H
#define DOWNLOADMANAGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtNetwork>

class DownloadManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DownloadManager(
            QObject* parent = nullptr);

    void connectProgressSlot(
            std::function<void(qint64, qint64)>& progress_slot);

    static bool isHttpRedirect(
            QNetworkReply *reply);

signals:
    void progressChanged(
            const int& current,
            const int& maximum);

public slots:
    void startDownloading();
    void downloadFinished(
            QNetworkReply* reply);
    void sslErrors(
            const QList<QSslError> &errors);

protected:
    QQueue<QString> m_remaining_urls;

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager m_manager;
    std::function<void(qint64, qint64)>* m_progress_slot;
};

#endif // DOWNLOADMANAGER_H
```

**downloadmanager.cpp**

```
#include "downloadmanager.h"

DownloadManager::DownloadManager(
        QObject* parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_manager(NULL),
    m_progress_slot(NULL)
{
    connect(&m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

bool DownloadManager::isHttpRedirect(
        QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    return statusCode == 301 || statusCode == 302 || statusCode == 303
           || statusCode == 305 || statusCode == 307 || statusCode == 308;
}

void DownloadManager::connectProgressSlot(
        std::function<void(qint64, qint64)>& progress_slot)
{
    m_progress_slot = &progress_slot;
}

void DownloadManager::startDownloading()
{
    // Download the file at the top of the queue...
    if(!m_remaining_urls.isEmpty())
    {
        QString download_url = m_remaining_urls.dequeue();

        QNetworkRequest request(download_url);
        QNetworkReply* reply = m_manager.get(request);

        #if QT_CONFIG(ssl)
            connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), SLOT(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
        #endif

        if(m_progress_slot)
        {
            connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, *m_progress_slot);
        }
    }
    else {
        // FL: Emit download finished
    }
}

void DownloadManager::downloadFinished(
        QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    QUrl url = reply->url();
    if (reply->error()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Download of %s failed: %s\n",
                url.toEncoded().constData(),
                qPrintable(reply->errorString()));
    } else {
        if (isHttpRedirect(reply)) {
            fputs("Request was redirected.\n", stderr);
        } else {
            //QString filename = saveFileName(url);
            //if (saveToDisk(filename, reply)) {
                qDebug() << "Download of " << url << "succeeded";
            //}
        }
    }

    reply->deleteLater();

    startDownloading();
}

void DownloadManager::sslErrors(
        const QList<QSslError>& errors)
{
#if QT_CONFIG(ssl)
    for (const QSslError &error : errors)
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL error: %s\n", qPrintable(error.errorString()));
#else
    Q_UNUSED(sslErrors);
#endif
}
```

**patchmanager.h**

```
#ifndef PATCHMANAGER_H
#define PATCHMANAGER_H

#include "downloadmanager.h"

class PatchManager : public DownloadManager
{
public:
    explicit PatchManager(
            QObject* parent = 0);

    void startPatching();

signals:
    void progressChanged(
            const int& current,
            const int& maximum);

public slots:
    void downloadFinished(
            QNetworkReply* reply);

private:
    QVector<QString> m_files_to_download;
};

#endif // PATCHMANAGER_H
```

**patchmanager.cpp**

```
#include "patchmanager.h"

PatchManager::PatchManager(
        QObject* parent) :
    DownloadManager(parent)
{

}

void PatchManager::startPatching()
{
    // This loop should NOT block because we were placed into a different thread...
    while(true)
    {
    // Just for testing, give sample URLs.
    const QString patch_server_url = "https://www.w3.org/";
    const QList<QString> files_to_patch = {"TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"};

    for(int i = 0; i < files_to_patch.size(); i++)
    {
        m_remaining_urls.enqueue(patch_server_url + files_to_patch[i]);
    }

    startDownloading();
    }
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include "patchmanager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    PatchManager patcher;

    QThread patch_thread;
    patch_thread.start();

    patcher.moveToThread(&patch_thread);

    patcher.startPatching();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>526</width>
    <height>245</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>160</y>
      <width>491</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>491</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>491</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>526</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: In the member initialiser list of your `DownloadManager` ctor try changing `m_manager(NULL)` to `m_manager(this)`.

Comment: Your bug is here `patcher.startPatching();` this forces the code to block the GUI. Make `startPatching()` a slot and emit a signal to that slot. Make sure your connection from your signal to this slot uses `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Comment: @drescherjm how would I create a connection.. I'm assuming something like this... but not sure what that first parameter should be. connect(what goes here?, Qt::QueuedConnection, patcher, &PatchManager::startPatching);

Comment: You could add a signal to MainWindow. Also `Qt::QueuedConnection` is the last parameter to connect().

Comment: A way to call startPatching is to use invoke methode : `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&patcher, "startPatching", Qt::QueuedConnection )`